# Keeping track of task number in multi threaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm writing a multi threaded application, where one part of the code must be thread safe to keep track of task numbers.

I have this method:

```
private void IncrementTaskNumber() {
   Interlocked.Increment(ref _TaskNumber);
}
```

_TaskNumber is a private int in the same class. The problem is, this throws me a "A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter" exception.
To get around this, I do:

```
private void IncrementTaskNumber() {
   int _taskNum = _TaskNumber;
   Interlocked.Increment(ref _taskNum);
   _TaskNumber = _taskNum;
}
```

Is this still thread safe?

Comment: Show the declaration of `_TaskNumber` please.  Given the error message, it sounds like it's defined as something like `private int _TaskNumber { get; set; }` - is that correct?

Comment: @Reed Copsey, yes private int _TaskNumber {get; set;}

Comment: You need to use a field, not a private property - see my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> _TaskNumber is a private int in the same class.

`_TaskNumber` has to be a private *field* for this to work.  You likely have it as a private property.

Define it as:

```
private int _TaskNumber;
```

And it will work.

Also note that your current workaround introduces a race condition - you're effectively getting rid of the atomic increment by doing it using a temporary variable, which defeats the purpose of using `Interlocked` in the first place.  You need to increment the field directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was easier tham expected :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have a locking mecanism in the `IncrementTaskNumber` method. Unless you call it only from one place, it is not thread safe. The first implementation you wanted to do, even if it would have worked wouldn't have been either since `Interlocked.Increment(ref _TaskNumber);` might have been called a second time before the first would have been done, and writen to the ref parameter.

Edit:
If you want to make it threadsafe, you could modify yoru method like this :

```
private void IncrementTaskNumber()
{
    lock (_TaskNumber)
        _TaskNumber++;
}
```

Edit 2: (You might want to look into other solutions if using `lock` is too costy for your application.)

Comment: If using a lock to perform one increment per task is too expensive, you probably have bigger problems.

Comment: @Servy With small work bodies, a lock can become very prohibitively expensive.  There's a huge amount of plumbing in the TPL to avoid having to lock exactly for that reason...

Comment: @ReedCopsey If this was something that needed to be done frequently in a loop, then I'd agree, but since it's done only once per task if it's a real problem then it probably means you have too many tasks doing units of work that are too small.

Comment: @Servy True - it depends on what comprises a "Task"

Comment: If you start/handle enough threads that the lock becomes the bottleneck, THAT is the problem. I suggested the lock solution taking into account it's done in that context.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not thread-safe:

```
private void IncrementTaskNumber() {
   int _taskNum = _TaskNumber;
   Interlocked.Increment(ref _taskNum);
   _TaskNumber = _taskNum;
}
```

since a thread executing the sequence could be interrupted between each of these 3 operations. This won't work unless you introduce a loop that keeps retrying to increment if the local value changed in the meantime, but that would basically mean you are reimplementing `Interlocked.Increment` using `Interlocked.Increment`. :)

Just make `_TaskNumber` a *member* variable, not a property.